# R: How do I write "≥2: n=nrow(x)" in plot legend?

Tags: r

I am doing boxplots and have problems with the legend. Specifically, I want to write "≥2: n=formatC(nrow(x))" but can not combine the commands for the ≥ symbol, the function that calculates `nrow(x)` and `formatC(nrow(x), bigmark=",")` that should give the nrow number with a thousand separator.

What I tried so far:

```
smoke <- matrix(c(1:1200),ncol=1,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(smoke) <- c("High")
smoke <- as.table(smoke)

pdf('test.pdf')
plot(NA,xlim=c(0,100),ylim=c(0,100))
legend(10,70,bquote(paste(NA>=2, ": n=", .(formatC(nrow(smoke)), big.mark=","))))
dev.off()
```

which gives: `≥ 2: n=1200`

I would like to have: `≥2: n=1,200`

It seems that formatC does not work under bquote and I would also like to remove the space after the ≥ symbol.

I also tried:

```
legend(x,y, legend=c(expression(NA>=2), paste(": n=", formatC(nrow(smoke)), sep="")))
```

which gives the legend in two lines: 
`≥ 2
: n=1200`

Putting `paste` before `expression` gives one line but does not convert the >= to ≥.

I am exporting the graph as pdf, which currently works for the ≥ symbol. I would prefer to keep that. Unicode does not work with pdf in my hands.

Thanks in advance,
Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `)` in the wrong place right after `smoke`, so it takes the `big.mark` argument as part of `paste` and not `formatC`. Try this:

```
legend(10,70,bquote(paste(NA>=2, ": n=", .(formatC(nrow(smoke), big.mark=",")))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not spot that mistake. Is there also a way to remove the space between ≥ and 2?

Comment: @user3485328 You can remove the space either by using `paste0` instead of `paste` or specifying `sep = ""` in your `paste` call.

Comment: @user3485328 there is no extra space between `≥` and `2`. If you do just `legend(10,70,bquote(3>=2))` you'll see that it's just the regular space.